# Change the size of a button in gwidgets2

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets

```
windo <- gwindow(title="Calculator Buttons",visible=TRUE)
grp = ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=windo)
gbutton("Hi how do I reduce my size",container = grp)
gbutton("cannot find an option to specify size",container = grp)
```

Hi, I am doing an R UI and want see that the buttons get added vertically as the horizontal argument is FALSE, in both ways I am not able to control the size of the button. I am looking to fit two buttons in a row of a reasonable length.

Comment: You might try the `size() <-` function on your button widgets, but it may not work. You can often control size by passing in arguments of `expand=...` or `fill=...` to the constructor. These are passed on to the underlying `add` method of the container. With a vertical packing box, the buttons should expand in the horizontal direction, but these two arguments allow you to control more.

Comment: Just to add to @jverzani's comment, I would reference the buttons, e.g. `p1 =gbutton(...)`, and then either do `size(p1) = c(500, 20)` or `size(p1) = list("width" = 500, "height" = 20)` (I think this one is more reliable... at least when I used it) to change the height and width of the button.

Comment: @jav I am getting Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] unknown option "-height".

Comment: @makarandkulkarni It's been a while since I used this package but perhaps look at https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-in-command-library-rcmdr/33817/2. In this, it is mentioned to try running directly via the R GUI to see if it works.